# I try to download a google file, there isn't errors but it doesn't work

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm developing an app with google drive and I can see my files with these app. I want to download the files, but I can't.
This is my function, is equal to google documentation:

Thanks un advance!!

```
  /* Download a file's content.
   * 
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param file Drive File instance.
   * 
   * @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
 public static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) throws IOException
 {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0)
     {
     try
     {
     HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();
     return resp.getContent();
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
     // An error occurred.
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
     }
     }
    else
     {
     // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
     return null;
     }
 }
```

No errors in Logcat, but I don't see any file in downloads, sd-card, etc

If there isn't error, I have to see very carefull in sd-card, system etc?

it's necessarely anything else??

Comment: Check out this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog It shouldn't matter that it is google drive, because you are using a URL anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the file content and returning an `InputStream` however your code doesn't show what you are doing with this `InputStream`. You need to use it to save the content of the file to Disk or database etc... Please have a look at the link that [FaddishWorm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723618/faddishworm) sent you in comments which writes the file to the SD Card: [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)